# Add lines to top of text file, retain formatting

Tags: text, formatting

I have a config file to which I nee to add a couple of lines at the top of the file.
When I try to do it from the command line, it removes the new line characters from my file and gives me an unformatted file.

So, my question is: Can I add some lines to the top of an already existing file and it should retain its formatting and new lines remain as new lines?

I am adding new lines to an existing file from another file.

Comment: How are you wanting to accomplish this? What language? You can easily open it in notepad or vi and do exactly what you are looking to do.

Comment: I am making an automated script to do the above. Hence the requirement for a shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, you could create a new file with the additional information and then copy it plus the original file to a new file.  Assuming you have an existing file called config.txt and a new file called new.txt:

copy new.txt+config.txt newConfig.txt

Or, you could **type** the old file and append to new.txt:

type config.txt >> new.txt

I think the second option would work in Linux, using the **cat** command rather than **type**.

Either way you'll neeed to delete the old config file and rename the new one.

If you want to do it in code:

- allocate a buffer that's large enough to hold the combined file (i.e. length of old file + length of new file)
- Read the new file into memory at the beginning of the buffer
- Read the old file into memory starting at the byte after where the new file ended
- Save the buffer to disk